# zend framework 3 how can call phtml file in controller

Tags: zend-framework

I want to get html content in controller .
for this

```
public function posteemailAction(){
  $view=$this->render("auth-acl/email/_getemail.phtml");
   print_r($view);die;

}
```

Can anyone help for getting content of html in controller. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "getting content of html in controller"?

You want to have the predefined html content of a view (the content of the phtml file?
You want to get the rendered content (the one seen by the user) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function ajaxAction() {
        // Turns off the layout and the view
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); 
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

        // Creates a new instance of Zend_View
        $html = new Zend_View();

        // Set a script path for above view
        $html->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/scripts/your_custom_path/');

        // Assinging some data to the view
        $html->assign('myVar', $someValue);

        // Renders the view to specified variable
        $responseContent = $html->render('mycontent.phtml');

        echo $responseContent;
}
```